# One versus one approach multiclass in r

Tags: r

Supposing My dataset is iris  with 3 classes and I want to implement one versus one SVM approach but when i subset the training set for each classifier by `class i` and `class j`, I get an empty subset (follow this line `#selecting subset of training set where Species equal to class i and class j`)

```
Species <-iris$Species
class <- unique(Species)
set.seed(123)
s<- sample (150,100)
data_train<- iris[s,]
data_test<- iris[-s,]
train <-data_train
test <-data_test
for(i in 2:length(unique(Species))-1){
  for(j in (i+1):length(unique(Species))){
    print(paste(class[i],class[j],sep=","))


    #selecting subset of training set and testing set where coronaryEvent equal to class i and class j
    train <-subset(train, Species %in% c(class[i],class[j]))
   str(train)


  }}
[1] "setosa,versicolor"
'data.frame':   0 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Sepal.Length: num 
 $ Sepal.Width : num 
 $ Petal.Length: num 
 $ Petal.Width : num 
 $ Species     : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 
[1] "setosa,virginica"
'data.frame':   0 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Sepal.Length: num 
 $ Sepal.Width : num 
 $ Petal.Length: num 
 $ Petal.Width : num 
 $ Species     : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 
[1] "versicolor,virginica"
'data.frame':   0 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Sepal.Length: num 
 $ Sepal.Width : num 
 $ Petal.Length: num 
 $ Petal.Width : num 
 $ Species     : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..:
```

Comment: Can you share your dataframe with a `dput()`?

Comment: it's too long to share i am not allowed to share long code here

Comment: Can you then share a fake dataset? Without it it's difficult to reproduce your problem.

Comment: 'data.frame': 213 obs. of  72 variables:
 $ Diagnosis                           : int  2 3 3 3 3 2 3 2 3 1 ...
 $ Indication                          : int  2 2 2 3 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...$ CoronaryEvent                       : Factor w/ 6 levels "CABG","Died",..: 3 3 2 3 2 3 3 3 3 3 ...

Comment: is it clear like this

Comment: It's still not reproducible. Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example-aka-mcve-minimal-complete-and-ver

Comment: head(data)
  Diagnosis Indication Clopidogrel.Clopidogred.dose Time.of.collection..Hours.
1         2          2                            4                          1
2         3          2                            4                          2
3         3          2                            6                          1
4         3          3                            4                          1
5         3          2                            6                          1
6         2          2                            4                          2

Comment: i wanna subset data by row CoronaryEvent with value of class i and value of class j

Comment: thanks now it works for(i in 1:length(unique(CoronaryEvent))-1){
   for(j in (i+1):length(unique(CoronaryEvent))){
       print(paste(i,j,sep=","))
    print( class[i])
    print( class[j])
    }}

Comment: for(i in 1:length(unique(CoronaryEvent))-1){
   for(j in (i+1):length(unique(CoronaryEvent))){
       print(paste(i,j,sep=","))
    print(paste(class[i], class[j],sep=","))
   
        }}

Comment: I tried with iris dataset any suggestion?? @Barbara

Answer (score 1):

This should be working:

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(123)
s<- sample (150,100)
data_train<- iris[s,]
data_test<- iris[-s,]
train <-data_train
test <-data_test
#train$Species <- as.factor(as.character(train$Species))
class <- unique(iris$Species)


for(i in 2:length(unique(iris$Species))-1){

  for(j in (i+1):length(unique(iris$Species))){
    print(paste(class[i],class[j],sep=","))

    class_i <- factor(as.factor(class[i]))
    class_j <- factor(as.factor(class[j]))


    train2 <- rbind(train[match(as.character(train$Species), class_i, nomatch = FALSE), ], 
                    train[match(as.character(train$Species), class_j, nomatch = FALSE), ])

    train2
    str(train2)


  }}
```

What I did is to assign the `iris$Species` value directly to `class` and changed a bit the `subset`. Let me know if this works as expected.

Comment: Unfortunately i got incorrect results because > table(data_train$Species)

    setosa versicolor  virginica 
        36         31         33

Comment: the results [1] "setosa,versicolor"
'data.frame': 100 obs. of  5 variables:...[1] "setosa,virginica"
'data.frame': 100 obs. of  5 variables:[1] "versicolor,virginica"'data.frame': 0 obs. of  5 variables:

Comment: By this example it should be "setosa,versicolor"  a df of 67  observations "setosa,virginica" a df of 69 observations and "versicolor,virginica" a df of 64 observations

Comment: @RawiaHemdan updated my answer, now it returns the expected results